# Program that ensures three lists have the same amount of elements

Tags: python, list

I am currently trying to build python code that removes the last element in a list in the case that any of three lists's lengths do not equal to each other. This would save time going back into the lists and manually `listExample{}.pop()` to certain lists every time the criteria is not met.

The list with the **lowest length** should be the desired length of elements for all three lists. In this example, it would be four elements but ideally the program should count the lengths of the three lists and grab the lowest integer as it's target. If the lists do not equal to each other, then the program will `.pop()` from the correct lists until `listLength1 == listLength2 == listLength3` is met.

Here are the lists and variables I created to set up the example:

```
listExample1 = ['FirstElement', 'SecondElement', 'ThirdElement', 'ForthElement', 'FifthElement', 'SixthElement']
listExample2 = ['FirstElement', 'SecondElement', 'ThirdElement', 'ForthElement']
listExample3 = ['FirstElement', 'SecondElement', 'ThirdElement', 'ForthElement', 'FifthElement']

listLength1 = len(listExample1)
listLength2 = len(listExample2)
listLength3 = len(listExample3)

print(listLength1) #6
print(listLength2) #4
print(listLength3) #5
```

Here is code I am currently building to attempt this:

```
if listLength1 == listLength2 == listLength3:
    pass
elif listLength1 < listLength2:
    pass 
elif listLength1 > listLength3:
    pass
elif listLength1 == listLength2:
    pass 
elif listLength2 < listLength1:
    pass
elif listLength2 > listLength3:
    pass
elif listLength2 == listLength1:
    pass
elif listLength3 < listLength3:
    pass
elif listLength3 > listLength1:
    pass
elif listLength3 == listLength2:
    pass
else:
    pass
```

The if/elif seems redundant and I feel like there is room for error when I start `listExample1.pop()` in a certain condition which would likely mess up down the line. What is the best way to approach this?

Desired output:

```
print(listExample1) #['FirstElement', 'SecondElement', 'ThirdElement', 'ForthElement']
print(listExample2) #['FirstElement', 'SecondElement', 'ThirdElement', 'ForthElement']
print(listExample3) #['FirstElement', 'SecondElement', 'ThirdElement', 'ForthElement']
```

Comment: `minLength = min(listLength1, listLength2, listLength3)`, followed by three loops of the form `while len(listExample1) > minLength: listExample1.pop()`.  You don't have to do anything special for the shortest list, its loop will simply do nothing.

Comment: Why do you want to do that with pops? That does not seem like the right tool.

Comment: Removing the last element from the list will not skew the data in the beginning is the idea with the pop

Comment: Will a slicing method be better used here ? For example get the minimum list length and store it as n. From then you can cut all the list until n like "listExample1 = listExample1[:n]"

Comment: @bbsmfb I meant why use pop to achieve that, instead of `del` (answered that by now).

Comment: @KurtRojas That does unnecessary work, with unnecessarily much code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
n = min(listLength1,listLength2,listLength3)

for i in range(listLength1-n):
    listExample1.pop()    
for i in range(listLength2-n):
    listExample2.pop()
for i in range(listLength3-n):
    listExample3.pop()

print(listExample1)
print(listExample2)
print(listExample3)
```

Output

```
['FirstElement', 'SecondElement', 'ThirdElement', 'ForthElement']
['FirstElement', 'SecondElement', 'ThirdElement', 'ForthElement']
['FirstElement', 'SecondElement', 'ThirdElement', 'ForthElement']
```

Comment: you will get three equal lists of the same length

Answer (score 3):

You'd better have them in a list of lists. Then delete the unwanted suffixes.

```
n = min(map(len, lists))
for L in lists:
    del L[n:]
```

More efficient than popping elements one by one or copying prefix slices.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of popping iteratively, we can simply use this.

```
listExample1 = ['FirstElement', 'SecondElement', 'ThirdElement', 'ForthElement', 'FifthElement', 'SixthElement']
listExample2 = ['FirstElement', 'SecondElement', 'ThirdElement', 'ForthElement']
listExample3 = ['FirstElement', 'SecondElement', 'ThirdElement', 'ForthElement', 'FifthElement']

lengths = [len(listExample1) ,len(listExample2) ,len(listExample3)  ]

minL = min(lengths)

listExample1 = listExample1[:minL]
listExample2 = listExample2[:minL]
listExample3 = listExample3[:minL]

print(listExample1)
print(listExample2)
print(listExample3)
```

Output came as

```
['FirstElement', 'SecondElement', 'ThirdElement', 'ForthElement']
['FirstElement', 'SecondElement', 'ThirdElement', 'ForthElement']
['FirstElement', 'SecondElement', 'ThirdElement', 'ForthElement']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the minimum length using the min function. Then run a for loop for each list, popping out the last element if needed.

```
listExample1 = ['FirstElement', 'SecondElement', 'ThirdElement', 'ForthElement', 'FifthElement', 'SixthElement']
listExample2 = ['FirstElement', 'SecondElement', 'ThirdElement', 'ForthElement']
listExample3 = ['FirstElement', 'SecondElement', 'ThirdElement', 'ForthElement', 'FifthElement']

minLen = min(len(listExample1),len(listExample2),len(listExample3))

for _ in range(len(listExample1)-minLen):
    listExample1.pop(-1)

for _ in range(len(listExample2)-minLen):
    listExample2.pop(-1)

for _ in range(len(listExample3)-minLen):
    listExample3.pop(-1)

print(listExample1)
print(listExample2)
print(listExample3)
```

Comment: After you find "minLen", why don't you just copy the first minLen number of elements from each list to themselves.  Like...listExample1 = listExample1[:minLen]

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```py
def reduce_size(*sequences):
    min_length = min(len(sequence) for sequence in sequences)
    return (sequence[:min_length] for sequence in sequences)

list1 = ['FirstElement', 'SecondElement', 'ThirdElement', 'ForthElement', 'FifthElement', 'SixthElement']
list2 = ['FirstElement', 'SecondElement', 'ThirdElement', 'ForthElement']
list3 = ['FirstElement', 'SecondElement', 'ThirdElement', 'ForthElement', 'FifthElement']

list1, list2, list3 = reduce_size(list1, list2, list3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Slicing is possible:

```
min_len = min(len(a), len(b), …)

a = a[:min_len]
b = b[:min_len]
…
```

Answer (score 1):

Not so much different from the previous comments, but I would prefer just to slice the lists and to return a copy of them if they aren't too big.

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
l2 = [3,4,5,6]
l3 = [1,2]

m = min(map(len, (l1,l2,l3)))
for i in [l1,l2,l3]:
    print i[:m]
```

RESULT:

```
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
[1, 2]
```

Comment: Indeed not so much different ... from the 3 previous answers that also did this slicing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a "cute" way, that has the advantage of working for arbitrary iterables:

```
list1 = ['FirstElement', 'SecondElement', 'ThirdElement', 'ForthElement', 'FifthElement', 'SixthElement']
list2 = ['FirstElement', 'SecondElement', 'ThirdElement', 'ForthElement']
list3 = ['FirstElement', 'SecondElement', 'ThirdElement', 'ForthElement', 'FifthElement']

list1, list2, list3 = map(list, zip(*zip(list1, list2, list3)))
```

If `tuples` are fine for your result, then just

```
list1, list2, list3 = zip(*zip(list1, list2, list3))
```

also works.